# ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock works only in PageLoad event

Tags: c#, asp.net, registerclientscriptblock, clientscript

I'm trying to register a simple script -

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "myscript", "<script>testfun();</script>");
```

This line works fine when I put it in the page load event. However, everytime the user selects a row in the gridview, I need some client side function to get executed, hence in the GridView.SelectedIndexChanged event, I added the same line, however, it doesn't work there. Can anyone point out why this happens or direct me towards a more elegant solution?

Comment: Try RegisterStartupScript? If you have UpdatePanel surrounding your control. You can use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript.

Comment: Why do you register the script on the next postback? You should do that on the initial load, then you could even omit the postback on SelectedIndexChanged if you want.

Comment: Actually, I have 2 sections on my page, both are in a separate updatepanel, so the whole page doesn't load when the SelectedIndex changes, which is when I want the script to run. Hence, calling this in the initial load won't work. Am i right? @TimSchmelter

Comment: @madatanic RegisterStartupScript isn't working either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RegisterClientScriptBlock` does not execute your script but only emits it into the page that is then sent to a client. It is a programmatic equivalent of having a `*.js` file. The script is only executed when the resulting HTML page is loaded on the client. If you want some java script to run on particular control's event you need to hook up a `javascript` method to it like that:

```
onclick="javascript_method();"
```

For this to work you must have `javascript_method()` defined in a `*.js` file or added to your page via `RegisterClientScriptBlock`